# inncorrect date validation when year like 'dd.mm.0302' or '27.08.0974' in JS

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have a problem with date validation from database, some years in the date fields are incorrect (like 28.02.**0302**), i must validate them. I try some functions from web but they validate this date as valid. How to get them work? 
Here function that i tried:

```
function isValidDate(d) {


if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
    return false;
  return !isNaN(d.getTime());

}

function isValidDate11(s) {
    // format D(D)/M(M)/(YY)YY
    var dateFormat = /^\d{1,4}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,2}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,4}$/;

    if (dateFormat.test(s)) {
        // remove any leading zeros from date values
        s = s.replace(/0*(\d*)/gi,"$1");
        var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);

        // correct month value
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1]-1;

        // correct year value
        if (dateArray[2].length<4) {
            // correct year value
            dateArray[2] = (parseInt(dateArray[2]) < 50) ? 2000 + parseInt(dateArray[2]) : 1900 + parseInt(dateArray[2]);
        }

        var testDate = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);
        if (testDate.getDate()!=dateArray[0] || testDate.getMonth()!=dateArray[1] || testDate.getFullYear()!=dateArray[2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This date IS valid in some way. Do you have any specific restrictions for your date?

Answer (score 0):

Because the date you are trying:  28.02.0302 with your script actually change that date to the 28 of February of the year 2202. So it's actually a valid date.

There are two part of that script that result in your date actually being checked as 2202:

This part remove leading Zeroes from the date values making the year from 0302 to 302.

```
// remove any leading zeros from date values
   s = s.replace(/0*(\d*)/gi,"$1");
```

This second part check if the date is less than 4 characters and add 2000 if is less than 50 and 1900 if is more.

```
    // correct year value
    if (dateArray[2].length<4) {
         // correct year value
        dateArray[2] = (parseInt(dateArray[2]) < 50) ? 2000 + parseInt(dateArray[2]) : 1900 + parseInt(dateArray[2]);
    }
```

The second part is a bit more tricky. I guess that it was made to validate a date of 01.01.12 as 01/01/2012 and a date of 01.01.93 as 01/01/1999

Those are not really necessary and you can change the function to:

```
function isValidDate11(s) {
    // format D(D)/M(M)/(YY)YY
    var dateFormat = /^\d{1,4}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,2}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,4}$/;

    if (dateFormat.test(s)) {
        var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);
        // correct month value
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1]-1;

        var testDate = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);

        if (testDate.getDate()!=dateArray[0] || testDate.getMonth()!=dateArray[1] || testDate.getFullYear()!=dateArray[2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
       }
   } else {
        return false;
   }
}
```

Still the date 28.02.0302 is valid because it get checked as the 28 of February of the year 302.

So to get an exact answer you should probably say exactly what you consider a valid date and what you don't.

Since you have trouble with 0302 I guess you might want a date with a 4 numbers year that doesn't have a leading zero:

```
function isValidDate11(s) {
    // format D(D)/M(M)/YYYY
    var dateFormat = /^\d{1,4}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,2}[\.|\/|-]\d{4}$/;

    if (dateFormat.test(s)) {
           // remove any leading zeros from date values
        s = s.replace(/0*(\d*)/gi,"$1");
        var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);
        // correct month value
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1]-1;

        if(dateArray[2].length != 4){
          return false;
        }

        var testDate = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);

        if (testDate.getDate()!=dateArray[0] || testDate.getMonth()!=dateArray[1] ||     testDate.getFullYear()!=dateArray[2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will fix your 0302 year problem but will not work with a date ending with a year with only two carachters .14

Comment: Thanks, i will try your code, for me years like 0302 or 0947 (start with 0) are inncorrect, and i must interpret them as wrong, i create report, that do some checks with personal data, and if this date is wrong then in report i mark that field wrong